# Azure ML Web App Template Error

Tags: r, azure, templates, web-applications, azure-machine-learning-service

Hi I'm new to Azure ML but really am interested in what it has to offer.

I have built a model using R code and Azure ML, deployed it as a web service and finally using the web app template I have converted it into an app service. However when I test it within the app it gives me the following error,

> "*{"error":{"code":"LibraryExecutionError","message":"Module execution
>   encountered an internal library
>   error.","details":[{"code":"FailedToEvaluateRScript","target":"Execute
>   R Script Piped (RPackage)","message":"The following error occurred
>   during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in
>   size(x[, pos]) : \n error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting
>   a method for function 'size': Error in validObject(x, complete = TRUE)
>   : \n invalid class \"itemMatrix\" object: item labels not
>   unique\n"}]}}* "

Which I interpret as saying that it cannot read the R script. I find this confusing as when I test it as a web service it works perfect. Can you please adviseme what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is, or what should be x ? The error message doesn't tell it can't read the script, but it can't évaluate it, and it seems that this issue is related to non unique labels somewhere  .. ?

Comment: Hi MrSmith, thanks for asking. I would assume that 'X' is the dataframe being used for the model, in this case it is a csv file with a list of product purchases.

Comment: Do you use the same .csv file for testing the webservice and the webapp  ? In that case, it is hard to help you with the informations you provided. Could you provide data sample, reproductible code .. and some more explanations ?